# Spring Boot datasource initialization error with data.sql script after 2.5.0 upgrade

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a project configured with `Spring Boot` and `Spring Data JPA`.

My project contains the following `data.sql` initialization script (I'm just starting developing my application that's why I use an embedded H2 database):

```
INSERT INTO Project(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Project 1');
```

And I'm defining the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    protected Project() {
    }

    public Project(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    // ...
}
```

I don't have any other configuration/setup in place.

```
ERROR 5520 ---[  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               :Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/path/project/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO Project(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Project 1'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "PROJECT" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Project(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Project 1') [42102-200]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/path/project/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO Project(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Project 1'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "PROJECT" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Project(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Project 1') [42102-200]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:622)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254)
...
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "PROJECT" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Project(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Project 1') [42102-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
```

Of course, before the upgrade, the application was starting just fine.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**TL;DR**

It seems `Spring Boot` has modified how it initializes the `DataSource` with `SQL` scripts with `2.5.0`.

This can be fixed by including the following property in the project:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
```

The explanation:

Among the changes introduced in **2.5.0**, it seems now the `data.sql` script is executed before Hibernate is initialized:

- [Spring Boot 2.5 Release Notes - Hibernate and data.sql](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#hibernate-and-datasql)

And since I'm relying on the ORM mechanism (i.e. Hibernate) to create the schema from the entity definition, the database table does not exist at the moment the initialization SQL script is executed.

Comment: all of these answers seem like they would apply to my project because I'm using 2.6.1, but I'm still seeing the error: "Table "TABLE_NAME" not found from "Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer'"

Comment: Are you sure your application is configured to create the schema out of the model classes @BrentFisher? You can check for example that `spring.jpa.generate-ddl` is not set to `false` and you can set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` (or `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`) to `create` just to be sure. 
If this doesn't solve your issue then you can share your solution (maybe post a new question?) and I can try to help you figure it out :)

Comment: About `the database table does not exist at the moment the initialization SQL script is executed` ... so why an exception was not thrown if the table does not exist? I mean, the data where was executed? In what table?

Answer (score 13):

Add `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true` to the `application.properties` file.

**Reason**:

By default, the `data.sql` scripts are now run before **Hibernate** is initialized. This aligns the behavior of basic script-based initialization with that of `Flyway` and `Liquibase`. If you want to use `data.sql` to populate a schema created by Hibernate, set `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization` to **true**. While mixing database initialization technologies is not recommended, this will also allow you to use a schema.sql script to build upon a Hibernate-created schema before it’s populated via `data.sql`.

**Source**:

[Spring Boot 2.5 Release Notes - Hibernate and data.sql](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#hibernate-and-datasql)

Answer (score 4):

Hope it help somebody. I was also having the same issue, my data.sql file was not picked so only blank tables were
generating. I used below mentioned properties and it worked for me:

```
    spring.sql.init.mode=always
    spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_CONTAINER_NAME:localhost}:3306/${MYSQL_DATABASE:uber}
    spring.datasource.username=${MYSQL_USER:boca-user}
    spring.datasource.password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD:boca-password}
    spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization = true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you can make ORM vendor create the schema for you, and after that import the data by `data.sql`

To achieve that you also need another property: `spring.sql.init.mode: always`

My total set of relevant properties are the following:

```
spring:
  sql.init.mode: always
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/products
    username: 
    password: 
  jpa:
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use data.sql to populate a schema created by Hibernate, set spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization to true.

***data.sql** OR **schema.sql** file should be save it in main/resources*

Spring Boot version 2+ has a minor change. All DDL(Data Definition Language) - Table Creations and data updates should be done in **schema.sql**

To resolve this issue just add this, and use this because '*the **data.sql** or **schema.sql** is getting executed before our tables are created in the  H2 database and we want to delay that' that's why we use this property'*

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization = true
```

to **application.properties** Configuration file.

or

```
spring:
  jpa:
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
```

Add the above if you using yml to your **application.yml** Configuration file.

**For Example for H2 In Memory Configuration**

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization = true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.sql.init.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:todo
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

Sometimes I've got a SQL Syntax Error when executing the spring boot application because of forgetting the **semicolon(;)** at the end of CREATE TABLE and sometimes **SYSDATE()** and **NOW()** have a problem using **NOW()** for the current date, so make sure to write the correct SQL syntax for DDL or DML

Comment: It solved my problem, very helpful. I used SYSDATE() that's why i got the error, then i used NOW(), and it worked.
Sometimes we got SQL syntax errors in the console but we think that our configuration is incorrect. Kindly check the error, it will be helpful in future coding

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue, I just added **@Entity(name="table_name")** and error got resolved.

application.properties file content:

```
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization = true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.sql.init.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:ToDo
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a schema.sql file, it will run before data.sql